# ansible: pull data from remote repository and run another task if data changed

Tags: git, ansible

For job automation I need to pull data from remote repository and do some tasks after. But tasks should be run only when data is changed.

Another words: pull source from the repo and rebuild app only when sources was changed

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Get data from repo
  git:
    repo: "{{ repo }}"
    dest: ""{{ local_path }}""
    clone: yes
    force: yes
    version: "{{ branch }}"
  register: data_changed

- name: build changes if changed
  shell: |
     bash -c "any shell script here"
  when: data_changed.before != data_changed.after
```

**when: data_changed.before != data_changed.after** is true anly when data chaged during 1-st task